# From ND to 1D arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an array `a`:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

I would like to convert it to a 1D array (i.e. a column vector):

```
b = np.reshape(a, (1,np.product(a.shape)))
```

but this returns

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

which is not the same as:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

I can take the first element of this array to manually convert it to a 1D array:

```
b = np.reshape(a, (1,np.product(a.shape)))[0]
```

but this requires me to know how many dimensions the original array has (and concatenate [0]'s when working with higher dimensions)

Is there a dimensions-independent way of getting a column/row vector from an arbitrary ndarray?

Answer (score 388, accepted):

Use [np.ravel](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy-ravel) (for a 1D view) or [np.ndarray.flatten](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) (for a 1D copy) or [np.ndarray.flat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html#numpy-ndarray-flat) (for an 1D iterator):

```
In [12]: a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

In [13]: b = a.ravel()

In [14]: b
Out[14]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Note that `ravel()` returns a `view` of `a` when possible. So modifying `b` also modifies `a`. `ravel()` returns a `view` when the 1D elements are contiguous in memory, but would return a `copy` if, for example, `a` were made from slicing another array using a non-unit step size (e.g. `a = x[::2]`).

If you want a copy rather than a view, use

```
In [15]: c = a.flatten()
```

If you just want an iterator, use `np.ndarray.flat`:

```
In [20]: d = a.flat

In [21]: d
Out[21]: <numpy.flatiter object at 0x8ec2068>

In [22]: list(d)
Out[22]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: <pedantic>In this example, `ravel()` returns a view, but that is not always true.  There are cases where `ravel()` returns a copy.</pedantic>

Comment: `a.ravel()` looks to be around three times as fast as `a.reshape(-1)`. `a.flatten()` is way slower, as it needs to make a copy.

Answer (score 31):

```
In [14]: b = np.reshape(a, (np.product(a.shape),))

In [15]: b
Out[15]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

or, simply:

```
In [16]: a.flatten()
Out[16]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: May use `b = a.reshape(-1)` for short in first example.

Answer (score 17):

I wanted to see a benchmark result of functions mentioned in answers including [unutbu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13730506/5300303).

Also want to point out that [numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) recommend to use `arr.reshape(-1)` in case view is preferable. (even though `ravel` is tad faster in the following result)

---

> **TL;DR**: [`np.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) is the most performant (by very small amount).

### Benchmark

Functions:

- [`np.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html): returns view, if possible
- [`np.reshape(-1)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html): returns view, if possible
- [`np.flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html): returns copy
- [`np.flat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html): returns [`numpy.flatiter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatiter.html). similar to [`iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)

numpy version: '1.18.0'

#### Execution times on different `ndarray` sizes

```
+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|  function   |   10x10  |  100x100  | 1000x1000 | 10000x10000 |
+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| ravel       | 0.002073 |  0.002123 |  0.002153 |    0.002077 |
| reshape(-1) | 0.002612 |  0.002635 |  0.002674 |    0.002701 |
| flatten     | 0.000810 |  0.007467 |  0.587538 |  107.321913 |
| flat        | 0.000337 |  0.000255 |  0.000227 |    0.000216 |
+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

#### Conclusion

> `ravel` and `reshape(-1)`'s execution time was consistent and independent from ndarray size.
>   However, `ravel` is tad faster, but `reshape` provides flexibility in reshaping size. (maybe that's why [numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) recommend to use it instead. Or there could be some cases where `reshape` returns view and `ravel` doesn't).
>   If you are dealing with large size ndarray, using `flatten` can cause a performance issue. Recommend not to use it. Unless you need a copy of the data to do something else.

#### Used code

```
import timeit
setup = '''
import numpy as np
nd = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))
'''

timeit.timeit('nd = np.reshape(nd, -1)', setup=setup, number=1000)
timeit.timeit('nd = np.ravel(nd)', setup=setup, number=1000)
timeit.timeit('nd = nd.flatten()', setup=setup, number=1000)
timeit.timeit('nd.flat', setup=setup, number=1000)
```

Comment: You mention that there could be a case where `reshape` returns a view and `ravel` doesn't.  One such case is when `y=x[::2]`.  Because `y` is not contiguous, ravel must copy, even though it's already a 1D array.  You can use this to devise cases where ravel is slower.

Answer (score 7):

#### For list of array with different size use following:

```
import numpy as np

# ND array list with different size
a = [[1],[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8]]

# stack them
b = np.hstack(a)

print(b)
```

#### Output:

`[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]`

Comment: how would you get the shape of `a` back from `b` ?

Comment: If you want to divide 1D into chunks. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8495740/6117565

Answer (score 3):

One of the simplest way is to use `flatten()`, like this example :

```
 import numpy as np

 batch_y =train_output.iloc[sample, :]
 batch_y = np.array(batch_y).flatten()
```

My array it was like this :

```
    0
0   6
1   6
2   5
3   4
4   3
.
.
.
```

After using `flatten()`:

```
array([6, 6, 5, ..., 5, 3, 6])
```

It's also the solution of errors of this type :

```
Cannot feed value of shape (100, 1) for Tensor 'input/Y:0', which has shape '(?,)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't using the np array format, (to lazy to modify my code) this should do what you want...  If, you truly want a column vector you will want to transpose the vector result.  It all depends on how you are planning to use this.

```
def getVector(data_array,col):
    vector = []
    imax = len(data_array)
    for i in range(imax):
        vector.append(data_array[i][col])
    return ( vector )
a = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
b = getVector(a,1)
print(b)

Out>[2,5]
```

So if you need to transpose, you can do something like this:

```
def transposeArray(data_array):
    # need to test if this is a 1D array 
    # can't do a len(data_array[0]) if it's 1D
    two_d = True
    if isinstance(data_array[0], list):
        dimx = len(data_array[0])
    else:
        dimx = 1
        two_d = False
    dimy = len(data_array)
    # init output transposed array
    data_array_t = [[0 for row in range(dimx)] for col in range(dimy)]
    # fill output transposed array
    for i in range(dimx):
        for j in range(dimy):
            if two_d:
                data_array_t[j][i] = data_array[i][j]
            else:
                data_array_t[j][i] = data_array[j]
    return data_array_t
```

Answer (score 0):

**Best and fastest among all the suggested solutions: `np.reshape()`**

```
%timeit img1ary = np.reshape(img2ary,(np.product(img2ary.shape),1))
9.3 µs ± 69.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit img1ary = img2ary.ravel()
157 ns ± 1.32 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

%timeit img1ary = img2ary.flatten()
961 ns ± 5.77 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```