# how to make a for loop using the dimensions of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2-D array that is called dataSet which is 335 x 225. I want to fill a new empty array, called newDataSet, 1-D array that is 1 x 7537. The newDataSet should be filled from the first 7537 data points of dataSet. How can I do this?

I want to use it a for loop like so:

```
for row in trainingData.shape[0]
    for column in trainingData.shape[1]
    bin_1 = trainingData[:33,:255]
```

Comment: `7537` or `75375` ?

Comment: 7537. I want to make 10 new arrays that are made up of subsets of the original data. so the first 9 arrays (1-D) would have 7537 data and the last one would have 7542.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From ND to 1D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730468/from-nd-to-1d-arrays)

Comment: `trainingData.shape[i]` will always be an integer, which is not iterable. If you want to iterate *up to* that integer, use `range(trainingData.shape[i])` for whatever value of `i`

Comment: but I am not getting this: do you want a single array or a list of arrays in the end? A single array could be troublesome because you need some alignment as the data does not fit perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need for loops if you use numpy

```
import numpy as np    
dataset = np.random.random((335, 225))
```

First reshape the `dataset` in to a `1x(335*225)` array and then extract the first 7537 elements out of it

```
new_array = dataset.reshape(1, 75375)[:,0:7537]
```

Comment: Great Idea with the reshaping :) But also I dont want to reuse the data points from the original data. In other words, the first array should contain 1-7537, the second would contain 7536 - 15,073...etc. So would `new_array = dataset.reshape(1, 75375)[:,0:7537]` still work?

Comment: Use `arrays_1_to_9 = dataset.ravel()[0:7537*9].reshape((9, 7537))` and `last_array = dataset.ravel()[7537*9:]`. But there should be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

A one step method to generate your subsets :

```
subsets=np.split(a.ravel(),range(0,a.size,a.size//10)[1:-1])

In [30]: [len(s) for s in subsets]
Out[30]: [7537, 7537, 7537, 7537, 7537, 7537, 7537, 7537, 7537, 7542]
```

These are just views, so the data is not copied. It's normally not a problem for training sets.