# using two for loop together to convert 2D list to 1D list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

```
A = [1,3,5]
B = ['a','b']
for x in A , for y in B :
  print(x,y)
```

how we can implement two for loop and can convert 2D list in 1D list

desired output : [(1,'a') ,(2,'b') ,(3,'a') ,(3,'b') ,(5,'a'),(5,'b') ]

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730468/from-nd-to-1d-arrays

Comment: Please make your question clear, there's no 2D list in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide the desired output.

Comment: what is the length of 1D list output?

Comment: output is  [(1,'a'), (2,'b'), (3,'a'), (3,'b'), (5,'a'), (5,'b')]

Comment: ok, but where does the `2` come from?

Comment: oh sorry it's 3*

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53332512/edit) question and include desired output, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to iterate through two lists simultaneously you can use zip:

```
x = [1, 3, 5]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i, j in zip(x, y):
    print(i, j)  # Will print "1 a" followed by "3 b"
```

Note that zip will actually return a list of tuples containing the combined elements from both lists, and if the lists are not equal in length then the longer list will just be truncated

Comment: That's one interpretation - but then the OP did ask for `2` for loops. If you want less for loops: `print(*zip(x,y), sep="\n")` works too

Answer (score 0):

If you want equal distribution of elements in both lists:

```
A = [1,3,5]
B = ['a','b']

l = []

for x in A:
    for y in B:
        l.extend([x, y])                

>>> print(l)
[1, 'a', 1, 'b', 3, 'a', 3, 'b', 5, 'a', 5, 'b']
```

Comment: its giving  [[1, 'a']]
[[1, 'a'], [1, 'b']]
[[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [3, 'a']]
[[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [3, 'a'], [3, 'b']]
[[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [3, 'a'], [3, 'b'], [5, 'a']]
[[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [3, 'a'], [3, 'b'], [5, 'a'], [5, 'b']]

Comment: I can't reproduce that output from the given inputs, please test/edit here to show inputs how you get that output https://repl.it/@downshift/TurboFatalDatabases

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1,3,5]
B = ['a','b']

l = []
#for each element in A
for i in A:
    #for each element in B
    for o in B:
        l.append((i,o))
```

Iterate through each element in each list then append them together