# How to pass a Pandas column as a batch of sentences in a 1-D tensor of strings?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning

I am struggling to pass a Pandas column (or numpy array) with size `(2946, 1)` to a Text embedding input layer in Keras with Tensorflow 2. The Pandas DataFrame object is just 1 text column with 2946 different observations.

According to the Tensorflow hub [module documentation](https://tfhub.dev/google/Wiki-words-500-with-normalization/2) on this pre-trained word embeddings, the module:

> The module takes a batch of sentences in a 1-D tensor of strings as
>   input.

The network and input layer is defined as follows:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf
from tenorflow import keras


hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/Wiki-words-500-with-normalization/2",
                           input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(optimizer='Adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train.values, y_train, epochs=10, validation_split=0.20)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-cf8b37d02f89> in <module>()
      1 model.fit(X_train.values, y_train,
      2              epochs=10,
----> 3              validation_split=0.20)

8 frames
/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    571                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    572                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 573                            'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    574         if not check_batch_axis:
    575           data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected keras_layer_input to have 1 dimensions, but got array with shape (2946, 1)
```

How can I pass a pandas column or numpy array as a batch of sentences in a 1-D tensor of strings that the input layer expects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to flatten your `X.train.values` from `(2946, 1)` to just `(2946)`. If `X.train.values` is a `np.array` you can use `X.train.values.ravel()` or [several other choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730468/from-nd-to-1d-arrays). If it's not, just convert it to numpy.

Comment: UPDATE: Using `values.ravel()` does successfully passes it to the input layer now. However, I'm getting some `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 'func' argument to TF_GraphCopyFunction cannot be null` error but I guess that's unrelated to this question?

Comment: looks like it. If you feel stuck, just open a new question!