# How to put all pixels of an image with the method reshape in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, rgb, reshape, pixel

I have an image of shape (271, 300, 3) containing values between 0 and 1 (image/255)
And I would like to put all the pixels of this image in another variable (pixel) with the method reshape, how to do that ? Here is my few code

```
image = plt.imread('im3.jpg')
im = image/255.0
print(im.shape) #(271, 300, 3)
```

Until here, I've tried to do that :

```
pixels = im.reshape(im.shape[0]*im.shape[1]*im.shape[2])
```

but I don't think it is the way to do that.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730468/from-nd-to-1d-arrays

Comment: pixels = im.reshape(im.shape[0]*im.shape[1], im.shape[2]) will give you a 1D array of (r,g,b) values if that's what you want.

Comment: I'm only trying to put all the pixels of "image" in a new variable called "pixels"

Comment: shape `(271,300,3)` shows that you don't have pixels with single values 0...1 but with tuples `(RED,GREEN,BLUE)`  - see value `3` in shape. To reshape to pixels you need `reshape(271*300)` but you do `reshape(271*300*3)` which reshape to somethig different.

Comment: @ADL92 I don't understand. Can you please explain why do you need to use the method `reshape`? Why not using `pixels = im` or using "deep copy": `pixels = numpy.copy(im)` ?

Comment: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 243900 into shape (81300,)

Comment: It's from a work of my University, it's asked to use the method reshape, I just don't know why and how to do that....

Comment: and after doing that, this code must be exectued without error :                                fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(pixels[:,0],pixels[:,1],pixels[:,2],c=pixels)
plt.show()

Comment: try `reshape(271*300, 3)`

Comment: you should add this code in question - it explains your real problem. Asking only for reshaping was useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reshape it to flat array with pixels which have three values `(R,G,B)`

```
pixels = im.reshape( im.shape[0]*im.shape[1], im.shape[2] )
```

It will convert `(271, 300, 3)` to `(81300, 3)`

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

image = plt.imread('im3.jpg')
im = image/255.0
print(im.shape) #(271, 300, 3)

pixels = im.reshape(im.shape[0]*im.shape[1], im.shape[2])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(pixels[:,0], pixels[:,1], pixels[:,2], c=pixels)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! similarly with a variable containing a lot of images and of shape (1000, 32, 32, 3), it would be the same ? something like that : pixels = x.reshape(x.shape[0]*x.shape[1]*x.shape[2],x.shape[3])

Comment: if you want one result for all images at once then it should work.