# Convert Pandas DataFrame to One Numpy Array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I Have pandas dataframe like this.
[pd df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHuqz.png)

but i want to make the 'KDB' column something like this (without the index), does anyone can help me?

```
[9.  3. 3.  2.  .....]
```

I tried to use pd.DataFrame.to_numpy() but what i got is something like this..

```
[[ 9]
 [ 3]
 [ 3]
 [ 2]
 ...]
```

Comment: use the reshape function

Comment: `df.to_numpy().reshape(-1)`

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: That looks like a NumPy array, what's the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From ND to 1D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730468/from-nd-to-1d-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

all it did was give you the column that normal, you just have to reshape it and it will make it into a row.

Now all you have to do is reshape it with `df.reshape(-1)`
or do it all in one line with `df.to_numpy().reshape(-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the numpy.flatten() function to get a one-dimensional array:

```
>>> a = [[1], [2], [5]]
>>> a.flatten()
array([1, 2, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

A column of a pandas `DataFrame` is a Series.

The underlying numpy array used by a Series is accessible via `values`.

What you need is just:

```
df['KDB'].values
```