# how to convert array of array to single array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

here is my array, i tried some slicing operation

But it did not work

can someone tell me how to do that?

type is numpy.ndarray

```
x=[[10 34]
   [34 45]
   [12 12]
   [12 34]
   [23 23]]
```

I want to get a output like this -:

```
x=[10 34
   34 45
   12 12
   12 34
   23 23]
```

if

Comment: Try  `ravel` or `flatten` methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From ND to 1D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730468/from-nd-to-1d-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by:

```
    import numpy as np
x=[[10, 34],
   [34, 45],
   [12, 12],
   [12, 34],
   [23, 23]]
```

**First** without numpy:

```
flatten_x = [item for sublist in x for item in sublist]
```

**Second** with flatten:

```
flatten_x = np.array(x).flatten().tolist()
```

**Third** with ravel which is faster among all:

```
flatten_x = np.array(x).ravel()
```

**Fourth** with reshape:

```
flatten_x = np.array(x).reshape(-1)
```

Output:

```
print(flatten_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `x.reshape(-1)` and if you want to convert it to list then you can use `list(x.reshape(-1))`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the numpy function ravel as

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
a.ravel()
```

Result would be:
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])