# Attaching a numpy.ndarray of 'time since epoch' values to dataframe, but as a datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, epoch

In my dataframe named dfwiki, I have a column of elevation data(in mm) of countries from global mean sea level. I have a linear regression model which predicted the 'time since epoch', when the elevation will be 10 metres for respective countries.

```
expected_submerging = regr.predict(a)
```

here, 'a' was the elevation in mm.

```
type(expected_submerging)    #It is numpy.ndarray conataining epoch values
```

I want to attach this "expected_submerging" array back to my dataframe "dfwiki" as a column "Prediction", but in datetime format, not in epoch time in which it is now.
To be clear:

```
expected_submerging[:10]
```

gives:

```
array([[1.74646146e+13],
       [6.56033448e+12],
       [7.41266564e+12],
       [1.84929707e+13],
       [1.03031800e+13],
       [2.13093693e+13],
       [5.51344947e+12],
       [1.66030190e+13],
       [3.05836516e+12],
       [8.43175724e+12]])
```

On trying `dfwiki["predictions"]=(pd.to_datetime(expected_submerging,unit='s'))`
I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

On trying

```
ticks = expected_submerging.astype('datetime64[s]').tolist()
dfwiki["predictions"]=(pd.to_datetime(ticks,unit='s'))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Looks like you need to flatten the array `expected_submerging` first.

Comment: @MrFuppes How? I already tried using reshape(-1,1), I guess I don't know how to flatten!

Comment: this will help you @ArjuAman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730468/from-nd-to-1d-arrays

Comment: you can use `ravel()` to flatten; however are you sure about the unit (seconds)? how far in the future do you expect the dates to be? It might be necessary to use another datetime format than `pandas` datetime dtype as it can only be used up to year 2262

Comment: It's around year 2160, so it's pretty huge actually @MrFuppes

Comment: Correction: It's around year 2500, so it's pretty huge actually!!! @MrFuppes